# Azure Release - change active stage deployed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment

I wonder if there is anyone who can maybe assist.

I have roll back implemented on our releases, however with the database we don't release the last successful release. We roll back the backup we took of the database before we started with the release.

However, I need to show the users what the "Active" database deployment stage is like in the image. [Show Active Stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP5Ns.png).

I've gone through the API's but I must be missing something?

Please can anyone assist. I would truly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share more details about your expected behavior? Make the third database deployment stage highlight green?

Comment: Hi Walter,

Yes .. that is exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: I'm afraid you can only redeploy that stage in your old release. I used [update release definition API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) and changed the value of "currentRelease" but it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the info .. not good news :-(